# Scheduling long-running tasks using AWS services

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, architecture, scheduled-tasks, amazon-sqs

My application heavily relies on AWS services, and I am looking for an optimal solution based on them. Web Application triggers a scheduled job (assume repeated infinitely) which requires certain amount of resources to be performed. Single run of the task normally will take maximum 1 min.

Current idea is to pass jobs via SQS and spawn workers on EC2 instances depending on the queue size. (this part is more or less clear)
But I struggle to find a proper solution for actually triggering the jobs at certain intervals. Assume we are dealing with 10000 jobs. So for a scheduler to run 10k cronjobs (the job itself is quite simple, just passing job description via SQS) at the same time seems like a crazy idea. So the actual question would be, how to autoscale the scheduler itself (given the scenarios when scheduler is restarted, new instance is created etc. )? 
Or the scheduler is redundant as an app and it is wiser to rely on AWS Lambda functions (or other services providing scheduling)? The problem with using Lambda functions is the certain limitation and the memory provided 128mb provided by single function is actually too much (20mb seems like more than enough)

Alternatively, the worker itself can wait for a certain amount of time and notify the scheduler that it should trigger the job one more time. Let's say if the frequency is 1 hour:

```
1. Scheduler sends job to worker 1
2. Worker 1 performs the job and after one hour sends it back to Scheduler
3. Scheduler sends the job again
```

The issue here however is the possibility of that worker will be get scaled in.

**Bottom Line** I am trying to achieve a lightweight scheduler which would not require autoscaling and serve as a hub with sole purpose of transmitting job descriptions. And certainly should not get throttled on service restart.

Comment: "long-running tasks" .. "will take maximum 1 min" :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lambda is perfect for this. You have a lot of short running processes (~1 minute) and Lambda is for short processes (up until five minutes nowadays). It is very important to know that CPU speed is coupled to RAM linearly. A 1GB Lambda function is equivalent to a t2.micro instance if I recall correctly, and 1.5GB RAM means 1.5x more CPU speed. The cost of these functions is so low that you can just execute this. The 128MB RAM has 1/8 CPU speed of a micro instance so I do not recommend using those actually.

As a queueing mechanism you can use S3 (yes you read that right). Create a bucket and let the Lambda worker trigger when an object is created. When you want to schedule a job, put a file inside the bucket. Lambda starts and processes it immediately.

Now you have to respect some limits. This way you can only have 100 workers at the same time (the total amount of active Lambda instances), but you can ask AWS to increase this.

The costs are as follows:

- 0.005 per 1000 PUT requests, so $5 per million job requests (this is more expensive than SQS).
- The Lambda runtime. Assuming normal t2.micro CPU speed (1GB RAM), this costs $0.0001 per job (60 seconds, first 300.000 seconds are free = 5000 jobs)
- The Lambda requests. $0.20 per million triggers (first million is free)

This setup does not require any servers on your part. This cannot go down (only if AWS itself does).

(don't forget to delete the job out of S3 when you're done)

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. One more questions, what if instead of spawning many lambda functions, we just make few (let's say we create separate functions running every 5 mins, hourly, daily etc.). Each of the lambda functions will retrieve the jobs from s3 and pass them through sqs. Anything that can cause issues in this architecture?

Comment: You need to think about the structure of the s3 keys (filenames) so lambda functions don't include the files double (a lambda function doesn't know about the others). The nice thing is that you can trigger a lambda function on a S3 event, so you never have that problem. Then you can send it to SQS (every lambda function has one SQS call, this is not a problem and takes <1 second). But if you can batch it up, why not define the batch in 1 SQS ticket and leave out S3 and Lambda all together?

Comment: Could you elaborate what u mean by define the batch in 1 SQS ticket? Thanks

Comment: Instead of one job per SQS ticket, you define an array of jobs in one SQS ticket (or 1 batch). Then when you handle the ticket, the instance can handle the whole batch at once. In this case, the amount of SQS tickets is N/B where N is the amount of jobs you require and B is the batch size. So if you put 50 jobs in one ticket, you only need 200 SQS tickets for 10.000 jobs.

Comment: yup that is the plan. I will be running to Lambda functions to schedule those sqs tickets. So if there are 10k jobs to be run every 5 min, I will be passing 200 tickets through sqs to processing instance from Lambda function (scheduled function). But the jobs itself will be stored in s3 (but could dynamo db as an alternative) and fetched from lambda function on every cycle iteration

Comment: I want to suggest the use of SNS as an alternative, and perhaps better fitting event source for Lambda, as each job can be passed individually.